# Exception has occurred: UnidentifiedImageError cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000012D61FB1CC0>

Tags: python, image-processing, base64

```
import base64
from PIL import Image as pl

file = open('C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Sayac_Okuyucu\\sayac_okuyucu\\app\\rawdata.txt', 'rb')
encoded_data = file.read()
file.close() # readind byte raw data 

b  = base64.b64decode(encoded_data)
val = io.BytesIO(b)
img = pl.open(fp=val, mode='r') # ERROR IS HERE
img.save("test.jpeg")
```

**ERROR**

Exception has occurred: UnidentifiedImageError
cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000012D61FB1CC0>

---

I just wanna convert base64 to image but I getting the error. What should i do ?

Comment: The code looks correct. The issue is probably related to the content of `rawdata.txt`. `rawdata.txt` is probably not a valid base64 encoded image format (not representing a JPEG/PNG/TIFF/BMP... image). Try creating `rawdata.txt` using Python code (starting with valid image file). Example: `with open("in.png", "rb") as f:` and `data = base64.b64encode(f.read())`. Then `with open('rawdata.txt', 'wb') as f:` and `f.write(data)`.